Troubleshooting malloc Usage and heap_size Configuration in STM32 Development
I'm currently working with ST's ARM-M4 chip to develop a program and have ported a networking library. During debugging, I've noticed that if I don't increase the heap_size in my .s file to 0x400, the program crashes. I've already replaced the system's malloc interface with my own dynamic memory allocation function mymalloc. However, when I examine the .map linker file, I still see references to the malloc function in some file, yet I can't find the actual line of code where malloc is being called in the .map file.
My Questions:
In the MDK environment for ST, are there better methods to determine if the system's malloc function is being called? For instance, can breakpoints be set online?
Does the heap_size in the .s startup file on STM32 serve purposes beyond just dynamic memory allocation functions like malloc?
Besides dynamic memory allocation functions related to malloc, what other system library functions might use malloc?
My Attempts:
At the top of my header file, I used #define malloc mymalloc to replace the system's malloc.
I replaced the system's malloc with my own implementation using the library's malloc interface.

Dynamic allocation is a source of many problems in MCU programming. Avoid as a plaque and use static allocation instead or memory pools.

Do nm/readelf -s/objdump (or whatever the MDK equivalents are) on the individual .o/.a/.so files. This will show what files [still] want malloc. You can disassemble the given files to see which functions want it. Did you try building a malloc.o where you define mymalloc as malloc (vs the #define)? Any decent debugger should be able to breakpoint on malloc and give you a stack traceback. BTW, 0x400 isn't a lot of heap space even on an embedded system. So, what amount of heap space is acceptable to you? And why?


I used ARMCC's fromelf.exe tool to check the lw_int.o file, but did not find any malloc-related fields.

D:\000_soft\mdk5\ARM\ARMCC\bin\fromelf.exe --text -v lw_int.o | grep malloc

But there is a line in the .map file generated by my MDK:
sp_int.o(.text) refers to h1_alloc.o(.text) 

for malloc.

In addition to what @0___________ said, here is a list of numerous concrete reasons why you should not use it: Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?

"Besides dynamic memory allocation functions related to malloc, what other system library functions might use malloc?" strdup and getline would be the usual suspects. Or in case you mixed in C++, plenty of the standard headers.

Anyway, in case you have malloc in the map file then finding the culprit should be easy - just put a breakpoint inside malloc and check how you got there.


In the MDK environment for ST, are there better methods to determine if the system's malloc function is being called? For instance, can breakpoints be set online?

This is a long answer; see below.

Does the heap_size in the .s startup file on STM32 serve purposes beyond just dynamic memory allocation functions like malloc?

The stack will grow into the heap.  If the heap is not used, it extends the stack.  But if you don't define the heap, then that stack is just bigger.  It is hard to answer your question as some systems might use the heap for various things.  Generally, no, not normally.

Besides dynamic memory allocation functions related to malloc, what other system library functions might use malloc?

You can see the list here.  Ultimately, it is all just sbrk as per my original answer below.

Newlib documents sbrk use.
I use git grep -l sbrk inside a git repo of newlib for a list below.  There is a large comment sections in the source and it looks like a doc format.  For example, fread.c has this,
PORTABILITY
ANSI C requires <<fread>>.

<<fread_unlocked>> is a BSD extension also provided by GNU libc.

Supporting OS subroutines required: <<close>>, <<fstat>>, <<isatty>>,
<<lseek>>, <<read>>, <<sbrk>>, <<write>>.

This is a link to the formatted information.
List of sbrk files.
newlib/libc/posix/popen.c
newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c
newlib/libc/signal/psignal.c
newlib/libc/stdio/diprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/dprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fclose.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fcloseall.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fgetc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fgets.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fmemopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fopencookie.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fputc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fputs.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fread.c
newlib/libc/stdio/freopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fseek.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fseeko.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fsetpos.c
newlib/libc/stdio/funopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fwrite.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getc_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getchar.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getchar_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/gets.c
newlib/libc/stdio/nano-vfprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/open_memstream.c
newlib/libc/stdio/perror.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putc_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putchar.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putchar_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/puts.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setbuf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setbuffer.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setlinebuf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setvbuf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/siprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/siscanf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/sprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/sscanf.c
newlib/libc/posix/popen.c
newlib/libc/reent/Makefile.am
newlib/libc/reent/Makefile.in
newlib/libc/reent/reent.tex
newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c
newlib/libc/signal/psignal.c
newlib/libc/stdio/diprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/dprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fclose.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fcloseall.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fgetc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fgets.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fmemopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fopencookie.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fputc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fputs.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fread.c
newlib/libc/stdio/freopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fseek.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fseeko.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fsetpos.c
newlib/libc/stdio/funopen.c
newlib/libc/stdio/fwrite.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getc_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getchar.c
newlib/libc/stdio/getchar_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/gets.c
newlib/libc/stdio/nano-vfprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/open_memstream.c
newlib/libc/stdio/perror.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putc.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putc_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putchar.c
newlib/libc/stdio/putchar_u.c
newlib/libc/stdio/puts.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setbuf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setbuffer.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setlinebuf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/setvbuf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/siprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/siscanf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/sprintf.c
newlib/libc/stdio/sscanf.c

It is quite possible one of your networking functions use these.
Use of sbrk does not imply a malloc call, but this is the underlying use of heap  Using an idea of a breakpoint on malloc, a breakpoint on sbrk is probably more poignant.
All STM tools seem to just bundle newlib, it will be baked into the compiler (arm-none-eabi-gcc, which is a gcc version with a newlib version of libc).
From the same document/link on sbrk().
sbrk ¶
Increase program data space. As malloc and related functions depend on this, it is useful to have a working implementation. The following suffices for a standalone system; it exploits the symbol _end defined in the GNU linker script.
caddr_t sbrk(int incr) {
  extern char _end;     /* Defined by the linker */
  static char *heap_end;
  char *prev_heap_end;
 
  if (heap_end == 0) {
    heap_end = &_end;
  }
  prev_heap_end = heap_end;
  if (heap_end + incr > stack_ptr) {
    write (1, "Heap and stack collision\n", 25);
    abort ();
  }

  heap_end += incr;
  return (caddr_t) prev_heap_end;
}


Does the heap_size in the .s startup file on STM32 serve purposes beyond just dynamic memory allocation functions like malloc?

The line extern char _end; is the one related to the linker file and as the sbrk and 'allocation function' sections detail, this creates the 'heap' which is some concepts that most libc implementation stick to.
If you wrote a custom OS, you can redefine sbrk and for instance, assign MPU/MMU section as more memory is grabbed for a process.  The implementation above is for bare metal or single main line (well, maybe as others noted, you generally may wish to avoid this completely).

My Attempts: At the top of my header file, I used #define malloc mymalloc to replace the system's malloc. I replaced the system's malloc with my own implementation using the library's malloc interface.

It is better to replace the sbrk() inside of sysmem.c (or syscall.c)... depending on the specific STM32 tools you are using.  As an alternative of using a define to try and wrap malloc().
Reference: Newlib always fails

The C standard library uses the heap for handling the I/O, e.g. the printf function, see for example using printf consumes heap
If you don't want your program to use the heap, please avoid using function working on files like printf, or even better avoid using the C standard library at all, if this is possible.
If this is not possible, then you have to reserve a (minimal) amount of heap so that the C std library can allocate its structures.
If you have acces to the debugger, you can pinpoint heap accesses setting a breakpoint in the malloc function or in the h1_alloc you found in the map file, and checking the call stack you can figure out who uses the heap, most probably the C library initializations.

It uses a very special version of the standard library no file I/O, no dynamic allocation. Your answer does not answer anything and is completely wrong in the question scope. Also do not link 16 years old discussions

Many thanks for your reply!I think my reply answer e.g. the user question "For instance, can breakpoints be set online?". Furthermore, the MDK library the user mentioned seems to include the malloc function, please see e.g.: [link] (https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm__alloc_box.htm), so the dynamic allocation should be present,

This question is based on libc which a concept more than 16 year old.  I think the age of a discussion doesn't matter compared to relevance.  Please downvote my worthless answer as well.
